# Is flow battery cycle life really as high as the literature claims?

Tags: electrochemistry

I've seen a few reviews/journal articles now which claim that flow battery cycle life reaches the 10,000 mark and beyond with good capacity retention. However all of the primary sources I've came across only conduct tests for tens or hundreds of cycles, and there is almost always a significant capacity drop.

The general claim is that RFBs have a much better cyclability than solid state batteries such as lithium due to there being no physical change at the electrode, but I can't find any sources to back that up.

Can anyone show me a primary source which tests flow batteries (Preferably vanadium of iron chrome) for extended periods?